# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file1' referenced before assignment please help to fix

Tags: python, json

I need that when the button is clicked, the file_name variable is saved to a file. Please tell me how to fix my code:

```
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Open")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(False, False)

file_name = ""


def openu():
    global file_name
    if file_name == "":
        file_name = tfd.askopenfilename()
        with open("Filen.json", "w") as file1:
            json.dump(file_name, file1, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        os.startfile(file_name)
    else:
        with open("Filen.json", "r") as file1:
            json.load(file1)
        os.startfile(file_name)
    if btn1["text"] == "":
        btn1["text"] = file_name


btn1 =  tk.Button(window, text="", command=openu)
btn1.place(x = 20, y = 25)



window.mainloop()
```

UPD:
When you click on the button, the program opens a dialog box that opens the file. A File.json is created. Everything is displayed, but one thing does not work. I need that when restarting the program, the buttons are not empty. I changed the code, putting the full one.

Comment: If file_name is an empty string, then `file1` is never defined.

Comment: @JohnGordon Just a second, I'll reformulate the question now.

Comment: With the changes to this code, that error cannot happen anymore.  If you are still getting the error, then your real code must be different from what you have shown here.

Comment: @JohnGordon This code creates a file, opens the file that is specified on the button, but does not load the result from File.json. Also error: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: If you're loading from a file, use `json.load()`, not `json.loads()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Now it does not issue an error, but it does not load

Comment: You're not assigning the result of `json.load()` to a variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, I don't really understand the topic with loading. Can you please read more

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're having.  Please explain what the program is _doing_, and how that's different from what you _wanted_.  Otherwise I'm just guessing what you meant.

Comment: @JohnGordon When you click on the button, the program opens a dialog box that opens the file. A File.json is created. Everything is displayed, but one thing does not work. I need that when restarting the program, the buttons are not empty. I changed the code, putting the full one.

Comment: So this is now a tkinter question, and I don't know much about that.  You're probably better off asking a new question.

Comment: @JohnGordon Tkinter does not play a very important role here. The question is how to load the application path that opens through the dialog box

Comment: @FiolDoll: I'm not sure that I quite understand the question. It seems you already _know_ how to load the path from the file dialog. Do you mean _launch_ the path in another application? It seems you already know how to do that, too.

Comment: @SamMatzko 
The problem is that when restarting, saving to a variable does not work, the button remains empty, and the path needs to be done again

Comment: @FiolDoll: Thanks for clarifying! Now I understand. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. When the user opens the window, it loads the file path from the json file and automatically sets the button's text. When the user presses the button, it asks for a new file path name. More detailed explanations can be found in the comments in the code.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tfd
import json
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Open")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(False, False)

file_name = ""

def load_json():
    global file_name

    # Load the json file if it exists
    if os.path.exists("Filen.json"):
        with open("Filen.json") as file1:
            contents = json.load(file1)

            # If the json has a path in it, load the path to file_name
            # Otherwise, set file_name to an empty string ""
            if len(contents) > 0:
                if contents[0] != "":
                    file_name = contents[0]
                else:
                    file_name = ""
            else:
                file_name = ""

    # Create the json file if it does not exist
    else:
        with open("Filen.json", "w") as file1:
            json.dump([file_name], file1, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

def openu():
    global file_name

    # Load the json file
    load_json()

    # If file_name is still "", ask the user to input a file path
    path = tfd.askopenfilename()

    # If the user gave a path (did not hit Cancel), save path to file_name
    # and set the button's label
    if path != ():
        file_name = path

        btn1.config(text=file_name)

        # Save file_name to the json file
        with open("Filen.json", "w") as file1:
            json.dump([file_name], file1, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

# Load the json file, and put the file name into the button's text
load_json()
btn1 =  tk.Button(window, text=file_name, command=openu)
btn1.place(x = 20, y = 25)

window.mainloop()
```